# IE 11 FILE SELECTION ISSUE - FILES MISSING ON REMOTE CONNECTION

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have updated web page that was using flash to upload files. The updated page works on Edge Chromium, Edge Legacy, Chrome and Firefox. But on IE 11, I have a problem.

I have three systems 2 x Windows 10 and a Server 2019 VM running on one of the Windows 10 systems. All systems have IIS installed.  I have put the updated page / site on all systems.

If I connect to the local host in IE 11, files will upload to the local system, but if I am connected to one of the other systems / remote host then I run into a problem.

In the aspx page I have the following to allow browsing for files:

```html
<input type="button" id="BrowseFiles"  value="Browse Files" onclick="document.getElementById('FileNames').click();" />
<input type="file" id="FileNames" style="display:none;" multiple="multiple" onchange="ListFilesFunction()"/>
```

In the associated JavaScript I have:

```js
      var sfs = document.getElementById("FileNames");
```

When I am connected to the local host “files” appears in “sfs”, but when connected to another system / remote host “files” [ Object FileList ] does not appear, but as previously mentioned only on IE 11.

I hope I am missing something obvious, any thoughts on this?

Comment: Is the associated JavaScript in your `ListFilesFunction` function? If so, I've tested it on remote sever on IE and it can get the [object FileList]. You could check [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28zXp.gif). Which version of IE 11 are you using? Is there any error in console in your IE 11?

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, I discovered that I had left "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" option enabled in the "Compatibility View Settings".

Unchecking that option resolved the issue.